# Grails calendar plugin

Tags: grails, calendar, plugins

I have a groovy application which uses the grails calendar plugin [grails calendar plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/calendar).
Up to now I was using the calendar version 1.1.1 which has some bugs under IE.
I've upgraded to version 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT3 but now I am getting this exception, therefore
I had to downgrade to my previous version.

Any hint how to workaround this problem?

Thanks in advance, Luis

```
Error500:Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag &lt;g:form&gt;: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag &lt;calendar:datePicker&gt;: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.GregorianCalendar.setTime() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Thu Oct 08 11:38:42 CEST 2009]
Servlet: grails
URI: /smtool/grails/billingAccounting/show.dispatch
Exception Message: No signature of method: java.util.GregorianCalendar.setTime() is    applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Thu Oct 08 11:38:42 CEST 2009]
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag &lt;g:form&gt;: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag &lt;calendar:datePicker&gt;: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.GregorianCalendar.setTime() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Thu Oct 08 11:38:42 CEST 2009]
Class: GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but it seems that the program passed a wrong-type value into java.util.GregorianCalendar.setTime() function. You should try to find where the function is called in the source code. It will provide more information.